# Carbon timezone get timestamp

Tags: php, timezone, timestamp, php-carbon

I want to get a real timestamp of given time in specified timezone for using in frontend.

Currently i can set a timezone, and get the time for it. But i can't get a new one timestamp.

```
Carbon::setToStringFormat('U'); // Set __toString format
$instance = Carbon::createFromTimestamp('1460014482', "Europe/Kiev"); // Set global server timezone (or pickup from default PHP setting)
$instance->setTimezone("Indian/Maldives"); // Set user timezone

var_dump($instance->format('d M Y H:i:s')); // Shows the correct time +2 hours from Europe/Kiev

var_dump((string)$instance); // Shows the same timestamp specified in createFromTimestamp

var_dump(date('d M Y H:i:s', (string)$instance)) // So it won't show the timezone datetime
```

Explain how i can get a timestamp of time for a given timezone.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the function createFromFormat to use setTimezone. Here is an example for your code:

```
$originalDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", '1460014482');
$instance = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $originalDate, 'Europe/Kiev');
$instance->setTimezone("Indian/Maldives");
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know its not a complete solution. But it works for my requirements.
Currently need to override **__toString** method of Carbon class, which i use to display date timestamp.

```
public function __toString()
{
    return static::$toStringFormat == 'U' ? (string)strtotime($this->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) : $this->format(static::$toStringFormat);
}
```